# Validation for EditorFor helper mvc5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying a server validation for an appointment form. I use the bellow model

```
public class ProgramareMF
        {
        [Key]
        public int PacientID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Alege data la care vrei sa fi programat.")]
        public string DataProgramare { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Completati numele.")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "* Numele trebuie să aibă cel puțin 2 caractere.")]
        public string PacientNume { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Completati prenumele.")]
        public string PacientPrenume { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Emailul nu poate fi gol.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                            @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                            @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                            ErrorMessage = "Adresa de e-mail nu are formatul valid (ex: nume@domeniu.ro)")]
        public string PacientEmail { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Completati numarul de telefon.")]
        public string PacientTelefon { get; set; }
        public string PacientSimptome { get; set; }
        }
```

This is part of the view

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataProgramare, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Data Programare", @name = "datepicker"} }
                </div>
```

I've done similar work with account validation and worksfine the only difference there is that I use TextBoxFor helpe in razor for the input.

The controller methods that does the insert into database using a stored procedure are shown bellow

```
public class ProgramareMFBusinessLayer
        {
        public void AddAppointmentMF(ProgramareMF programareMF)
            {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MedicalDBContext"].ConnectionString;
            try
                {


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                SqlCommand cmdSp = new SqlCommand("spAddAppointmentMF", con);

                cmdSp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (var command = con.CreateCommand())
                    {

                    //command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //command.CommandText = "fnCreateAppoitmentXML";

                    SqlParameter paramPacientId = new SqlParameter();
                    paramPacientId.ParameterName = "@PacientId";
                    paramPacientId.Value = programareMF.PacientID;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramPacientId);

                    SqlParameter paramDataProgramare = new SqlParameter();
                    paramDataProgramare.ParameterName = "@DataProgramare";
                    paramDataProgramare.Value = programareMF.DataProgramare;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramDataProgramare);

                    SqlParameter paramPacientNume = new SqlParameter();
                    paramPacientNume.ParameterName = "@PacientNume";
                    paramPacientNume.Value = programareMF.PacientNume;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramPacientNume);

                    SqlParameter paramPacientPrenume = new SqlParameter();
                    paramPacientPrenume.ParameterName = "@PacientPrenume";
                    paramPacientPrenume.Value = programareMF.PacientPrenume;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramPacientPrenume);

                    SqlParameter paramEmail = new SqlParameter();
                    paramEmail.ParameterName = "@PacientEmail";
                    paramEmail.Value = programareMF.PacientEmail;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramEmail);

                    SqlParameter paramTelefon = new SqlParameter();
                    paramTelefon.ParameterName = "@PacientTelefon";
                    paramTelefon.Value = programareMF.PacientTelefon;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramTelefon);

                    SqlParameter paramSimptome = new SqlParameter();
                    paramSimptome.ParameterName = "@PacientSimptome";
                    paramSimptome.Value = programareMF.PacientSimptome;
                    cmdSp.Parameters.Add(paramSimptome);

con.Open();
                cmdSp.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
           //return ex.Message;
            }


[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProgramareMF(FormCollection formCollection)
            {
            BusinessLayer.ProgramareMF programareMF = new BusinessLayer.ProgramareMF();
            programareMF.PacientID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
            programareMF.DataProgramare = formCollection["DataProgramare"];
            programareMF.PacientNume = formCollection["PacientNume"];
            programareMF.PacientPrenume = formCollection["PacientPrenume"];
            programareMF.PacientEmail = formCollection["PacientEmail"];
            programareMF.PacientTelefon = formCollection["PacientTelefon"];
            programareMF.PacientSimptome = formCollection["PacientSimptome"];

            ProgramareMFBusinessLayer programareMFBusinessLayer = new ProgramareMFBusinessLayer();
            programareMFBusinessLayer.AddAppointmentMF(programareMF);

            return View();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Any idea why these code puts emtpy strings into the database and the attributes on the model are not triggerd???
Thanks

Comment: Make you POST method `public ActionResult ProgramareMF(ProgramareMF model)` - your model will be correctly bound and validation errors will be added to `ModelState` which you can test with `if(ModelState.IsValid)` (and if not valid then return the view. I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the basic tutorials.

Comment: The method is decorated with [HttpPost] attribute...

Comment: I know! (what does that have to do with it)

Comment: Sorry, I see now where is the problem, will work on that.